# UITableView How to call a function after reordering cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my project I wanted to implement moving rows as well as deleting them but not with stock "Delete" button but by tapping the image that is within my custom **UITableViewCell** called **QueueCell**. I delete rows in function **deleteByTap2** which uses the **sender.tag** (which is the **cell.indexPath.row**) to recognise which cell should be removed. Both moving and deleting work great on their own but when you move, for example, 6th row to 2nd it still carries the tag = 6 and because of that when I tap on image to delete the row, incorrect row gets deleted. I created a function **reTag** which is supposed to update tags of all cells within the sections and it works great after being called in **deleteByTap2** function but when called at the end of 
`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath)` 
it seems to not know the state of tableView after moving row. I searched the forum and I found that there was undocumented **UITableViewDelegate** function

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndReorderingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

but I tried calling it and it seems it was removed (or maybe name changed)
When should I call the **reTag** function so it would work properly? So it would know the order of tableView after reordering it?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! QueueCell
        let item = sungs[indexPath.section].songsIn[indexPath.row]
        cell.setup(item: item)
        if indexPath.section == 2{
            let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(deleteByTap2(_:)))
            tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
            tap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
            cell.artwork.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
            cell.artwork.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            cell.artwork.tag = indexPath.row
        }
        return cell
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    var toMove: MPMediaItem
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    if sourceIndexPath.section == 2{
            if player.isShuffle{
                toMove = player.shufQueue[player.shufIndex + sourceIndexPath.row + 1]
                player.shufQueue.remove(at: player.shufIndex + sourceIndexPath.row + 1)
                if destinationIndexPath.section == 2{
                    player.shufQueue.insert(toMove, at: player.shufIndex + destinationIndexPath.row + 1)
                }
            }else{
                toMove = player.defQueue[player.defIndex + sourceIndexPath.row + 1]
                player.defQueue.remove(at: player.defIndex + sourceIndexPath.row + 1)
                if destinationIndexPath.section == 2{
                    player.defQueue.insert(toMove, at: player.defIndex + destinationIndexPath.row + 1)
                }
            }
        }
    tableView.endUpdates()

    reTag(section: destinationIndexPath.section)
}
//the beginUpdates()-endUpdates() doesn't do much good here, actually it messes some of my cells

func reTag(section: Int){
        var indexPath: IndexPath
        for row in 0 ..< tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: section){
            indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
            if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? QueueCell{
                cell.artwork.tag = row
            }
        }
    }

func deleteByTap2(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        let tag = (sender.view?.tag)!
        if player.isUsrQueue{
            player.usrQueue.remove(at: player.usrIndex + tag + 1)
            player.usrQueueCount! -= 1
            sungs[2].songsIn.remove(at: tag)
        }else{
            player.defQueue.remove(at: player.defIndex + tag + 1)
            sungs[2].songsIn.remove(at: tag)
            player.defQueueCount! -= 1
        }
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: tag, section: 2)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        reTag(section: 2)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good example of why it's a bad idea to use `.tag` on objects to try and track them in this way.

I'd suggest that you move the tap gesture inside your cell class, and add a "call back" closure. This sample is, of course, missing your data class and `cell.setup()` code, but you should be able to see what needs to be changed:

---

```
// cell class
class QueueCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var artwork: UIImageView!

    var tapCallback: ((QueueCell) -> ())?

    func addTap() {

        if artwork.gestureRecognizers == nil {

            // cells are reused, so only add this once

            let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(artworkTap(_:)))
            tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
            tap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
            artwork.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
            artwork.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        }

    }

    func artworkTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) -> Void {
        tapCallback?(self)
    }

}
```

---

```
// table view class
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {

    // all you have to do is manage your data, 
    // no need to reload() or "re-tag" anything

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "QueueCell", for: indexPath) as! QueueCell

    // your cell configuration
    //let item = sungs[indexPath.section].songsIn[indexPath.row]
    //cell.setup(item: item)

    if indexPath.section == 2 {

        // tell the cell to add the gesture recognizer
        cell.addTap()

        // set the "call back" closure
        cell.tapCallback = {
            theCell in
            if let iPath = tableView.indexPath(for: theCell) {
                self.deleteByTap2(tableView, indexPath: iPath)
            }
        }

    }

    return cell

}

func deleteByTap2(_ tableView: UITableView, indexPath: IndexPath) -> Void {
    print("Tapped on artwork at:", indexPath)
    // you now have a reference to the table view and the indexPath for the cell that
    // contained the artwork image view that was tapped
}
```

Now your `deleteByTap2()` function will match the familiar `didSelectRowAt` function, and you can handle your deleting there.

Comment: I'm still beginner to Swift so I guess I have to study callbacks and closures more. This works flawlessly, thank you, Sir!